# Compute sum of large powers

Tags: algorithm, math

I have the following problem.
I have an array, that contains powers of -2.

For example, (3,4,5)

I need to calculate a sum of these powers, so the answer is: (-2)^3 + (-2)^4 + (-2)^5 = -8 + 16 -32 = -24.

If absolute value of sum is greater than 1000000, -1 should be returned.

The time complexity of the algorithm should be O(N*log(N)) and space complexity is O(N).

The catch is that the length of the array is up to 100,000 elements and each element could be up to 1,000,000,000.

I don't have any idea how to solve this.
Could you please advise?

Comment: This question belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Each exponent could be up to 1 billion or each "2^x" result could be up to 1 billion?

Comment: Is the array sorted? Can it contain duplicates?

Comment: Juan Lopes, Each exponent could be up to 1 billion. rici, array is not sorted and can contain dublicates.

Comment: You should give an example where the array elements aren't consecutive, since it greatly simplifies the problem.  Or are the numbers always consecutive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect the odd powers and the even powers and describe them as binary segments (once separated, duplicates can be simply processed according to the principle, 2^n + 2^n = 2^(n+1)). Conceptually subtract the smaller number from the larger (the larger will have the farthest 1 in a non-shared position). For example,

```
(-2) ^ 4  =>  { (0,3) 0; (4,4) 1 }
(-2) ^ 3 + (-2) ^ 5 => { (0,2) 0; (3,3) 1; (4,4) 0; (5,5) 1 }

Subtract the first from the second: 
    the segment starting at (4,4) borrows one 1 from the next segment.

{ (0,2) 0; (3,3) 1; (4,4) 1 } => 11000

Perform the 1048576 test by checking for any exponents (set 1's) above 19.

If the number is below 1048576, it can be easily converted from the 
segment list and output if it is lower than 1000001.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) so every (-2)^N you have got in O(log n). So the time complexity is O(n log n). The space complexity depends on length of the input table so that's O(n).

Comment: It's not so simple. 2^n has O(n) digits, it is only O(log n) when the multiplication is done in O(1). If by "each element could be up to 1,000,000,000" the OP means that each exponent could by up to 1 billion, O(1) multiplication wouldn't be possible.